AWSAppSyncClient Subscription error handler doesn't get triggered for Authorization errors of websocket in Angular 17+
I have an angular client ( Version 17+) that connects to AWSAppSync using AWSAppSyncClient library.
 client!: AWSAppSyncClient<any>;

 this.client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
            url: 'https://<AppSync EndPoint domain>/graphql',
            region: '<Region>',
            auth: {
                type: 'OPENID_CONNECT',
                jwtToken: async () => await this.AuthProvider.accessToken()
            },
            disableOffline: true,
        });

And the subscription as follows
this.client.hydrated().then((client: any) => {
            client.subscribe({ query:<GQLQUERY> }).subscribe({
                next: (data: any) => {
                    console.log('data', data);
                },
                error: (error: any) => {
                    console.error('error', error);
                },
            });
        });


whereas the network error is shown in the dev tools WS messages. However The error handler of the subscription doesn't get triggered for a while.

Any inputs/Guidance in this regard would greatly help.
Package details as follows
    "@angular/common": "^17.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^17.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^17.1.3",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "aws-appsync": "^4.1.10",
    "graphql": "^14.7.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",



switching to apollo/client from AWSAppSyncClient fixed the issue for us.
